# How to add object properties of an array and update it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects and i want to update `Total` value by adding months

```
var arrObj=[
  {name:"ABC",Jan:0,Feb:20,Mar:30,Apr:40,May:50,Jun:70,Jul:80,Aug:90,Sep:100,Oct:110,Nov:120,Dec:130,Total:0},
    {name:"BCD",Jan:10,Feb:20,Mar:30,Apr:40,May:50,Jun:70,Jul:80,Aug:90,Sep:100,Oct:110,Nov:120,Dec:130,Total:0},
   {name:"DEF",Jan:10,Feb:20,Mar:30,Apr:40,May:50,Jun:70,Jul:80,Aug:90,Sep:100,Oct:110,Nov:120,Dec:130,Total:0},
   {name:"FGH",Jan:10,Feb:20,Mar:30,Apr:40,May:50,Jun:70,Jul:80,Aug:90,Sep:100,Oct:110,Nov:120,Dec:130,Total:0}
]
```

I am updating the value using `loops` and it is working also but is there any best way to put this?

```
var len=arrObj.length;
var Total=0;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
arrObj[i].Total= +arrObj[i].Jan + +arrObj[i].Feb + +arrObj[i].Mar+ +arrObj[i].Apr+ +arrObj[i].May+ +arrObj[i].Jun+ +arrObj[i].Jul+ +arrObj[i].Aug+ +arrObj[i].Sep+ +arrObj[i].Oct+ +arrObj[i].Nov+ +arrObj[i].Dec;
}
console.log(arrObj)
```

```js
var arrObj=[
  {name:"ABC",Jan:0,Feb:20,Mar:30,Apr:40,May:50,Jun:70,Jul:80,Aug:90,Sep:100,Oct:110,Nov:120,Dec:130,Total:0},
    {name:"BCD",Jan:10,Feb:20,Mar:30,Apr:40,May:50,Jun:70,Jul:80,Aug:90,Sep:100,Oct:110,Nov:120,Dec:130,Total:0},
   {name:"DEF",Jan:10,Feb:20,Mar:30,Apr:40,May:50,Jun:70,Jul:80,Aug:90,Sep:100,Oct:110,Nov:120,Dec:130,Total:0},
   {name:"FGH",Jan:10,Feb:20,Mar:30,Apr:40,May:50,Jun:70,Jul:80,Aug:90,Sep:100,Oct:110,Nov:120,Dec:130,Total:0}
]
var len=arrObj.length;
var Total=0;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
arrObj[i].Total= +arrObj[i].Jan + +arrObj[i].Feb + +arrObj[i].Mar+ +arrObj[i].Apr+ +arrObj[i].May+ +arrObj[i].Jun+ +arrObj[i].Jul+ +arrObj[i].Aug+ +arrObj[i].Sep+ +arrObj[i].Oct+ +arrObj[i].Nov+ +arrObj[i].Dec;
}
console.log(arrObj)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are new to programming and I'm also assuming you have complete control over the data structure so if you already know this I apologize.

There is this concept called [data integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity). There are a few rules to this but the most important for the beginner to understand is what is the meaning of the data. In this case do you intact or change the data or do you just read from it?

With totals you don't interact with it directly it should be a calculation of other values and the only way to change it is by changing other values.

In JavaScript, there is the [Getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) which solves this problem.

Looks like this.

```js
const obj = {
  value: 3,
  get doubleValue () {
    return this.value * 2
  }
}
obj.doubleValue // 6
```

In your case, you can have something like this.

```
{
  get Total () {
    return ...calculation
  }
}
```

Here is a working example

```
{
  name:"ABC",
  Jan:0,
  Feb:20,
  Mar:30,
  Apr:40,
  May:50,
  Jun:70,
  Jul:80,
  Aug:90,
  Sep:100,
  Oct:110,
  Nov:120,
  Dec:130,
  get Total () {
    const keys = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    let sum = 0;
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      sum += this[key]
    })
    return sum
  }
}
```

So If you change any of the value then call Total it will automatically update.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function which gets the total from each object

```
const getTotal = obj => {
    let total = 0;
    const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    months.forEach(month => total += obj[month]);
    return total;
}
```

And then use it like

```
arrObj.forEach(obj => obj.total = getTotal(obj));
```

Comment: I like this declarative approach, quite better than loop and exclude the fields that are not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like below.

1. Loop through array elements
2. Filter out the unwanted keys
3. Reduce the remaining keys to get the total

```js
arrObj.forEach((element) => {
    element.Total = Object.keys(element).
            filter(key => key !== "name" && key !== "Total").
                reduce((acc,key) => acc + element[key], 0)
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop and exclude the fields `name` and `Total`. But it would be harder to read.

```js
var arrObj=[
  {name:"ABC",Jan:0,Feb:20,Mar:30,Apr:40,May:50,Jun:70,Jul:80,Aug:90,Sep:100,Oct:110,Nov:120,Dec:130,Total:0},
    {name:"BCD",Jan:10,Feb:20,Mar:30,Apr:40,May:50,Jun:70,Jul:80,Aug:90,Sep:100,Oct:110,Nov:120,Dec:130,Total:0},
   {name:"DEF",Jan:10,Feb:20,Mar:30,Apr:40,May:50,Jun:70,Jul:80,Aug:90,Sep:100,Oct:110,Nov:120,Dec:130,Total:0},
   {name:"FGH",Jan:10,Feb:20,Mar:30,Apr:40,May:50,Jun:70,Jul:80,Aug:90,Sep:100,Oct:110,Nov:120,Dec:130,Total:0}
]

for(let i in arrObj){
  for(let eli in arrObj[i]){
    if(eli != "Total" && eli != "name"){
      arrObj[i].Total += arrObj[i][eli];
    }
  }
}

console.log(arrObj);
```

The best way would be to have an Array inside the JS-Object and use the `reduce` function. But I may assume that this won't apply to your use-case.

```js
var arrObj=[
   {name:"BCD",months:[10,20,30,40,50,70,80,90,100,110,120,130],Total:0},
   {name:"DEF",months: [10,20,30,40,50,70,80,90,100,110,120,130],Total:0}
];

arrObj.forEach((e,i) => {
  arrObj[i].Total = e.months.reduce((a,b) => a+b);
});

console.log(arrObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `reduce` method:

```
var arrObj = [
        { name: "ABC", Jan: 0, Feb: 20, Mar: 30, Apr: 40, May: 50, Jun: 70, Jul: 80, Aug: 90, Sep: 100, Oct: 110, Nov: 120, Dec: 130, Total: 0 },
        { name: "BCD", Jan: 10, Feb: 20, Mar: 30, Apr: 40, May: 50, Jun: 70, Jul: 80, Aug: 90, Sep: 100, Oct: 110, Nov: 120, Dec: 130, Total: 0 },
        { name: "DEF", Jan: 10, Feb: 20, Mar: 30, Apr: 40, May: 50, Jun: 70, Jul: 80, Aug: 90, Sep: 100, Oct: 110, Nov: 120, Dec: 130, Total: 0 },
        { name: "FGH", Jan: 10, Feb: 20, Mar: 30, Apr: 40, May: 50, Jun: 70, Jul: 80, Aug: 90, Sep: 100, Oct: 110, Nov: 120, Dec: 130, Total: 0 }
    ];

arrObj.forEach(element => {
    let totalSum = Object.keys(element)
        .reduce((sum, key) =>{               
             return sum += parseFloat(element[key]) || 0
        }, 0);
    element.Total = totalSum;
});

console.log(arrObj);
```

Comment: The assumption that it adds any property that can be parsed to a float is great except the second time you run it.

Comment: @JasonHarwig thanks for your comment. I am sorry, could you show where it is looped the second time?

Comment: you aren't in this example, but if you were to extract this to a function it wouldn't be idempotent unless it ignored total, otherwise it'll add the total to the sum the second time.

Answer (score 0):

One can define a **getter property** of an **object** where the **total** gets **computed** on every **change of the properties** that depends on.

In **es6** one can use **class** and **get properties** to achieve this.

```
 Class MonthTotal {
    public Jan;
    public Feb;
    public MonthTotal(data) {
       this.Jan = data.Jan;
       this.Feb = data.Feb;
    }
    get Total() {
      return this.Jan + this.Feb;
    }
 }
 const monthData = new MonthTotal({ Jan: 10, Feb: 20});
 console.log(monthData.total); // logs :: 30
```

In **es5** we can leverage with a simple functional getter properties call

```
var monthData = { 
  name:"ABC",
  Jan:0,
  Feb:20,
  Mar:30
  get total() {
    return this.Jan + this.Feb + this.Mar;
  }
}

console.log(monthData.total); // logs :: 30
```